# NetBeans and build.xml

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, build.xml

When you create a project in NetBeans, it generates `build.xml` and `nbproject/build-impl.xml`. I had assumed it used both, but when I tried deleting `build.xml` as an experiment, NetBeans didn't seem to bat an eyelid. Is it the case that it only actually uses `nbproject/build-impl.xml` and I'm free to delete `build.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build.xml` is there for you to add hooks into the standard build, which is defined in build-impl.xml. I've never deleted it, and only changed it on rare occasions where I needed extra stuff done during the build.